# How to prevent a Django view that calls an external api from being flooded when it is called by a GET request?

Tags: django

I am writing a Django application with a view that is passed GET parameters. This view contacts an external API to get information, and passes the consolidated information to a template. The external API call is costly and limited. I am concerned that in a production environment, an attacker could write a script to repeatedly load the page with different parameters, (as I'm caching requests, so repeated calls with same parameters are fine), to exhaust my ability to use the external API.

I am trying to ensure that only humans can load my view (or specifically, reach the point of the external API call), or, at least, that a robot can't load it hundreds of times.

The most elegant solution would be some code in the view before the API call that could validate the user somehow. If the user failed the validation, they could be referred to another view or to a different template with a failure message. I am trying to do this as elegantly as possible and not be sloppy, however, so I'm looking for advice on best practice.

Initially, I intuitively wanted to use reCAPTCHA, however, it seems that this is generally used for forms. Adding reCaptcha to the form that directs to this page would not solve my problem, since the attacker could just run the attack by modifying the parameters in the url. Is there a way, either properly or with a hack, to test the user with an invisible, (or possibly visible, but I don't want to deter people by making them fill out a captcha every time), re-captcha in the view? I can't think of a way to do this, but perhaps it's possible.

Hopefully there is some external service or library that I could use to make a simple call to some sort of validator, which at least will block or heavily throttle a user if they are spamming my site, and, at best, would use more sophisticated methods to tell.

The view structure:

```
    def myView(request,query1,query2):

        results = call_external_api(query1, query2)
        return results to a template using context
```

Thanks for the help in advance, I hope I was clear in describing my problem!

Comment: You can throttle views, with `django-throttle-requests` https://pypi.org/project/django-throttle-requests/

Comment: It is very hard to prevent a DDoS attack, if someone really wants to attack your site then the requests will come from different IPs, won't respect cookies and will spoof request headers. Is it feasible to only allow logged in users to request that view?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I think that would create too much friction for site users. Additionally, I'm fairly sure it's against the TOS of the external API I'm using to put its content behind a login.

Comment: why does your view for the form POST redirect to the page rather than rendering the template with the API results directly?

Comment: @dirkgroten Sorry about that, I used the wrong term. I'm also used to developing Laravel apps, and views in Laravel are akin to templates in django. I meant template.

Comment: No I meant the initial view with the form. You say “the form that directs to this page”. Why not place the code calling the API in that form view? That way it’s protected by the captcha.